# Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC) filter and power line filter leakage

Tags: electrical-engineering, emc, electronic-filters

I have some questions regarding Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC) filtering  and power line filter leakage.

1. What will be the effect of leakage current of power line filter (2A)  when both power line and telephone line filters are installed on same enclosure having common ground and no RCD or GFCI device installed in the facility.  Will it create a hum in the phone lines?
2. What should be the line to ground capacitance of a power line filter for a 50Hz telephone line filter?
3. What should be the line to ground capacitance of a telephone line filter?